# Unit font does not match number font with siunitx

Tags: siunitx

I've looked already at previous threads, but nothing worked. So, I am using Sans Serif as a font in text mode (`\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}`) and standard Latin Modern as a font for math equations. I would like to have the unit also in Latin Modern when in math mode. I tried using `\sisetup{mode=match}` but it didn't work.

**EDIT:** Since I was a bit unclear, here is the photo of the problem.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Your code snippets leave a lot of details unspecified. Claims such as "it didn't work" aren't exactly specific. Hence, please edit your query to provide a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) (MWE) that generates the problem behavior you wish to fix.

Answer (score 2):

(I updated this answer completely after the OP provided some pertinent information about their document.)

To put the most important observation first, at the risk of coming across as needlessly harsh: You appear to have picked up some truly nasty and brutish LaTeX programming habits. E.g., instead of letting LaTeX create real paragraph breaks (by, say, inserting all-blank lines), your code is littered with `\\~\\` directives. And, instead of using the display math machinery that LaTeX and the `amsmath` package provide, your code has lots and lots of `center` environments, which should *not* be used for display-math purposes. My only advice is: Please unlearn these nasty habits -- the sooner, the better.

The code shown below should help you get started on this road. Note that the code now loads the package `sansmath` and executes `\sansmath`, so that math material is also rendered in sans-serif letters. In your posting, you mention that you use the Latin Modern font family. However, that's not the case -- at least not in the code you posted. If you need the Latin Modern font (and I would strongly agree with this thought!), I recommend you load the `lmodern` package.

Progressing, finally, to the question of your posting: Why doesn't the option `mode=match` work as (you) expect? It's because the `\qty` macro -- please note that the package's `\SI` and `\si` macros are obsolete; please make a habit of using `\qty` and `\unit` -- sometimes occurs in text mode, but at other times in math mode. What you want, I believe, is `mode=text`, not `mode=match`.

---

Here's an excerpt of the full pdf file that contains a few instances of `\qty` (which I've highlighted in yellow):

[image]

---

Here's how I would modify the file `settings.tex` -- most significant changes are gathered at the end of the file:

```
\usepackage{mathtools, 
            %amsfonts, % is loaded automatically by 'amssymb'
            %amsmath, % is loaded automatically by 'mathtools'
            amssymb, amsthm, thmtools, bm}


\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem} % why 'version=3'?

\usepackage{tabularx, booktabs, longtable, multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
%\usepackage{float} 
%\floatstyle{plaintop} 
%\restylefloat{table}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[labelfont={color=boja1,bf}]{caption}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage[croatian]{babel}
\usepackage[
    colorlinks=true,
    allcolors=boja1, % <-- use allcolors
    pdfusetitle,
    linktoc=none
]{hyperref}

\usepackage{geometry} \geometry{a4paper,hscale=0.75,vscale=0.8}
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}


%%%------------------------------------------------------------%%%

\fancyhead[L]{Vježba 9.2 \textit{Od bakra do bakra}}
\fancyhead[R]{Bruno Šijić}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}


\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\scriptsize\textcolor{boja1}{$\blacksquare$}}% level 1
\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{\scriptsize\textcolor{boja1}{$\square$}}% level 2
\renewcommand{\labelitemiii}{\textcolor{boja1}{$\circ$}}% level 3

\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\textbf{\textcolor{boja1}{\arabic*.}}}% level 1
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\textbf{\textcolor{boja1}{\alph*.}}}% level 2
\renewcommand{\labelenumiii}{\textbf{\textcolor{boja1}{\roman*.}}}% level 3


\makeatletter
\pretocmd{\tagform@}{\color{boja1}}{}{}
\renewcommand\@makefnmark{\hbox{\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\color{boja1}\@thefnmark}}}
\makeatother

\titleformat{\section}{\color{boja1}\Large\bfseries}{\thesection\enskip\color{gray}\textbar\enskip}{0cm}{} 
\titleformat{\subsection}{\color{boja1}\large\bfseries}{\thesubsection\enskip\color{gray}\textbar\enskip}{0cm}{}


%% New, 1 Apr 2023
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern, sansmath}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\sansmath % <-- use sans-serif math font
\usepackage{siunitx} 
\sisetup{mode=text, % <-- not 'mode=match'
         output-decimal-marker={,}} % <-- you need this too
%\setlength\parindent{0pt} % please don't do this
\usepackage{parskip} % instead, load the 'parskip' package
\frenchspacing
```

---

And here is how I would restyle the file `main.tex`. By the way, I am not a chemist and thus have no idea if the chemical formulas are correctly input or not.

```
\documentclass{article}
\input settings 

\definecolor{boja1}{RGB}{199, 25, 24}
\setlength{\headheight}{13.1pt}

\title{Vježba 9.2 \textit{Od bakra do bakra}}
\author{Bruno Šijić}
\date{\today} %{29. ožujka 2023.}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\thispagestyle{fancy} 


\section{Cilj vježbe}

Cilj vježbe jest provesti različite tipove kemijskih reakcija koje uključuju bakar te objasniti zabilježena opažanja.


\section{Uvod}

Bakar je kemijski element rednog broja 29. Pripada skupini prijelaznih metala koji imaju veliku gustoću, visoka tališta, dobru električnu i toplinsku vodljivost itd. Prijelazne metale karakterizira nepopunjenost d-orbitala pa će upravo zbog toga mnogi spojevi bakra biti intenzivno obojeni. Bakar u kemijskim spojevima može postojati u dva oksidacijska stanja (+I i +II). Spojevi bakra(II) stabilni su u vodenoj otopini i od njih većinom potječe plava boja. S druge strane, spojevi bakra(I) nisu stabilni u vodenoj otopini jer bakrovi(I) ioni disproporcioniraju na bakrove(II) ione i elementarni bakar.


\section{Opis korištene metode}

Vježba je provedena prema postupku opisanom u skripti \cite[str. 15]{skripta}. \textbf{UMETNI SLIKU!}


\section{Opažanja i eksperimentalni podaci}

Bakar je metal karakteristične crvenkastosmeđe boje. Koncentrirana dušična kiselina je bezbojna i prozirna tekućina. Reakcijom elementarnog bakra i koncentrirane dušične kiseline dolazi do pojave mjehurića, tj. nastajanja narančasto-smeđeg plina. Čaša se zagrijala, a unutar nje se nalazila otopina plave boje.

Dodatkom vodene otopine natrijevog hidroksida ($c = \qty{3}{mol.dm^{-3}}$) u dobivenu plavu otopinu došlo je do nastajanja želatinoznog taloga tamnoplave boje.

Zagrijavanjem nastalog sadržaja u čaši došlo je do promjene boje taloga iz tamnoplave u crnu, a otopina je postala bezbojna i prozirna. pH sadržaja ispitan je univerzalnim indikatorskim papirom pri čemu je on poprimio tamnozelenu boju. Nakon nekoliko ispiranja crnog taloga vrućom vodom, pH je opet ispitan te je univerzalni indikatorski papir porimio svjetlozelenu boju.

Dodatkom sumporne kiseline ($c = \qty{6}{mol.dm^{-3}}$) na crni talog došlo je do njegovog otapanja i ponovno je nastala otopina plave boje.

Kada je u tu otopinu dodan cink u prahu došlo je do burne reakcije u kojoj su se razvili mjehurići plina. Nastala je tvar crvenkastosmeđe boje, a plava otopina se obezbojila. Čaša s reakcijskom smjesom se zagrijala.

Početna masa bakra iznosi $m_1 = \qty{0,53}{\gram}$, a konačna masa $m_2 = \qty{0,50}{\gram}$. Iskorištenje reakcije jednako je
\begin{equation}
\eta = \frac{m_2}{m_1} = \frac{\qty{0,50}{\gram}}{\qty{0,53}{\gram}} = \qty{94}{\%}.
\end{equation}


\section{Rasprava i zaključak}

Egzotermnom reakcijom bakra i koncentrirane dušične kiseline nastaje narančasto-smeđi dušikov(IV) oksid i plava otopina bakrovih(II) iona
\[
\ce{Cu(s) + 2NO3^-(aq) + 4H3O^+(aq) -> Cu^2+(aq) + 2NO2(g) + 6H2O(l)}.
\]

Bakrov(II) ion u vodenoj otopini okružen je sa šest molekula vode čineći kompleksan spoj heksaakvabakrov(II) kation
\[
\ce{Cu^{2+}(aq) + 6H2O(l) -> [Cu(H2O)6]^{2+}(aq)}.
\]

Dodavanjem vodene otopine natrijevog hidroksida ($c = \qty{3}{mol.dm^{-3}}$) u plavu vodenu otopinu heksaakvabakrovih(II) iona nastaje tamnoplavi želatinozni talog tetraakvadihidroksobakra(II)
\[
\ce{[Cu(H2O)6]^{2+}(aq) + 2OH^-(aq) -> [Cu(H2O)4(OH)2](s) + 2H2O(l)}.
\]

Zagrijavanjem sadržaja, nastali tamnoplavi talog raspada se na crni talog bakrova(II) oksida i vodu
\[
\ce{[Cu(H2O)4(OH)2](s) ->[\Delta] CuO(s) + 5H2O(l)}.
\]

Zbog suviška natrijeve lužine pH nastale otopine bio je znatno veći od 7 zbog čega je univerzalni indikatorski papir poprimio tamnozelenu boju. Nakon nekoliko ispiranja taloga vrućom vodom, taj suvišak je uklonjen i pH otopine iznosio je približno~7.

Dokapavanjem sumporne kiseline na crni talog došlo je do njegovog otapanja i nastanka otopine plave boje, odnosno reakcije u kojoj nastaje vodena otopina heksaakvabakrovih(II) iona
\[
\ce{CuO(s) + 2H3O^+(aq) + 3H2O(l) -> [Cu(H2O)6]^{2+}(aq)}.
\]

Otopina bakrova(II) sulfata je kisela budući da u otopini prisutni heksaakvabakrovi(II) ioni podliježu protolitičkoj reakciji
\[
\ce{[Cu(H2O)6]^{2+}(aq) + H2O(l) <=> [Cu(H2O)5OH]^{+}(aq) + H3O^+(aq)}.
\]

Zbog prisutnih oksonijevih iona dolazi do burne egzotermne reakcije kada je u otopinu dodan cink u prahu pri čemu se razvija vodik
\[
\ce{Zn(s) + 2H3O^+(aq) -> H2(g) + Zn^{2+}(aq) + 2H2O(l)}.
\]

Elementarni cink također reagira s heksaakvabakrovim(II) kationom istiskivajući elementarni bakar karakteristične crvenkastosmeđe boje
\[
\ce{[Cu(H2O)6]^{2+}(aq) + Zn(s) -> [Zn(H2O)6]^{2+}(aq) + Cu(s)}.
\]


\section{Odgovori na pitanja}

\begin{enumerate}
   \item Napišite u koju skupinu kemijskih reakcija u vodenim otopinama pripada svaka od kemijskih reakcija. 
    
   \textcolor{boja1}{\textit{Rješenje.}}

   \begin{itemize}

   \item Taložne reakcije:
   \begin{gather*}
   \ce{[Cu(H2O)6]^{2+}(aq) + 2OH^-(aq) -> [Cu(H2O)4(OH)2](s) + 2H2O(l)},\\
   \ce{[Cu(H2O)4(OH)2](s) ->[\Delta] CuO(s) + 5H2O(l)}.
   \end{gather*}
   
   \item Redoks reakcije:
   \begin{gather*}
   \ce{Cu(s) + 2NO3^-(aq) + 4H3O^+(aq) -> Cu^2+(aq) + 2NO2(g) + 6H2O(l)},\\
   \ce{Zn(s) + 2H3O^+(aq) -> H2(g) + Zn^{2+}(aq) + 2H2O(l)},\\
   \ce{[Cu(H2O)6]^{2+}(aq) + Zn(s) -> [Zn(H2O)6]^{2+}(aq) + Cu(s)}.
   \end{gather*}
   
   \item Kiselo-bazne reakcije:
   \[
   \ce{[Cu(H2O)6]^{2+}(aq) + H2O(l) <=> [Cu(H2O)5OH]^{+}(aq) + H3O^+(aq)}.
   \]
   
   \item Kompleksirajuće reakcije:
   \[
   \ce{CuO(s) + 2H3O^+(aq) + 3H2O(l) -> [Cu(H2O)6]^{2+}(aq)}.
   \]
  \end{itemize}
  
  \item Je li reakcija koncentrirane dušične kiseline i bakra egzotermna ili endotermna? Kako to zaključujete?
  
    \textcolor{boja1}{\textit{Rješenje.}} Egzotermna jer se reakcijom oslobodila toplina, odnosno čaša, u kojoj se odvijala reakcija, se zagrijala.
    
    \item Zašto je pri dodatku cinka u otopinu potrebno paziti da nema plamena u blizini?
    
    \textcolor{boja1}{\textit{Rješenje.}} Zato što dolazi do reakcije u kojoj nastaje zapaljivi vodik.
    
    \item Ako bi konačno dobiveni bakar bio onečišćen sa cinkom kako bi ga mogli pročistiti?
    
    \textcolor{boja1}{\textit{Rješenje.}} Otapanjem u koncentiranoj dušičnoj kiselini i provođenjem elektrolize (s inertnim elektrodama) nad dobivenom otopinom. Na katodi će se izlučiti elementarni bakar, a na području oko anode će se oslobađati kisik.
\end{enumerate}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{literatura}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I edited my question, hope it makes more clear.

Comment: @crvenikupus - I'm afraid your addendum that shows a screenshot doesn't clear up anything. Sorry. As I wrote in my earlier comment, you need to show the LaTeX code, ideally in the form of a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that), that generates the problem behavior you wish to fix.

Comment: I am sorry, here it is: https://www.overleaf.com/read/qpknqrvcrdzc.

Comment: @crvenikupus - Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Don't link to an external source as it may disappear; many, like myself, will not go dashing off elsewhere.

Comment: @Mico Thanks for your answer and all the advice.